# EventHandler Not Needed in Event?

Tags: c#, delegates, eventhandler

I noticed this while using the Ping class. I originally followed C#'s documentation when implementing the PingCompleted callback method:

```
pingSender.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompletedCallback);
```

However, when I was adding a new method to the Timer's Elapsed event, I noticed that I wasn't passing a new TimerElapsedEventHandler. Instead, I was just passing the function name as is:

```
customTimer.Elapsed += CustomTimerElapsedCallback;
```

I tested this out with the PingCompleted event and it still works:

```
pingSender.PingCompleted += PingCompletedCallback;
```

I couldn't find any source that specifically explains why this is. Can anyone explain why this is allowed and what the EventHandler calls does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is handled by the C# compiler for you.  It was a [feature added in C# 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cz8t42e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (see section on ["How to: Declare, Instantiate, and Use a Delegate"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173176(v=vs.80).aspx)).

The C# Language Spec, Section 6.6, states:

> An implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from a method group (§7.1) to a compatible delegate type. Given a delegate type D and an expression E that is classified as a method group, an implicit conversion exists from E to D if E contains at least one method that is applicable in its normal form (§7.5.3.1) to an argument list constructed by use of the parameter types and modifiers of D

Basically, you can just use the name of a method in your code (which is a "method group", in your case, `CustomTimerElapsedCallback` or `PingCompletedCallback`), and the compiler will see that a delegate type is required, and put in the logic to do the conversion for you.

The resulting generated IL for `pingSender.PingCompleted += PingCompletedCallback;` and `pingSender.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompletedCallback);` are exactly the same as a result.

Comment: I see. Thank you! I couldn't find the answer anywhere else.